# how can I avoid the "Enter your name" message show up again?

Tags: python, function, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop

Basically when the employee_action function is called, and the user presses 1 or 2 and the data is printed to the terminal, after the user presses enter the message "enter your name" shows again and it assigns a new random number.

```
def employee_action():
    """
    Asks the user what they wish to do now that they're logged in.
    """
    while True:
        employee_input = input(
            "What do you wish to do today?\n1 Get Personal Data \n2 Get Survey Responses\n")
        if employee_input == "1":
            data = worksheet.get_all_values()
            for row in data:
                print(row)
            input("Press enter to continue.")
            break
        else:
            employee_input == "2"
            data = worksheet2.get_all_values()
            for row in data:
                print(row)

def new_employee_number():
    """
    Generates a new employee number making sure it doesn't already exist, allows the user to enter their name and adds the data to the Employee Data sheet.
    """
    new_employee_number = str(random.randint(0, 1000))
    new_employee_name = input("Enter your name:\n")
    while True:
        if new_employee_name.isalpha() and new_employee_number not in worksheet3.col_values(1):
            new_employee_name = new_employee_name.lower().capitalize()
            worksheet3.append_row([new_employee_number, new_employee_name])
            os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
            print(
                f"Welcome, {new_employee_name}! Your employee number is: {new_employee_number}\n")
            employee_action()
            break
        else:
            print("INVALID: Enter only letters\n")
            new_employee_name = input()
```

I tried breaking the loop and it doesn't seem to be working, I also asked [chat-gpt](/questions/tagged/chat-gpt) and didn't help me a lot either.

Comment: Please format your code. Surround it with ``` on both ends.  Use line breaks.  As it is now your code is nearly impossible to read.

Comment: can you show us the code where you call this functions? Post a minimal reproducible code that shows the problem you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to pinpoint the problem if you post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but if I had to guess I would say something is calling `new_employee_number()` over and over again. It's impossible to tell without showing the part where the `new_employee_number()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

There is something that does not make sense to me: In function `employee_action` you have:

```py
        ... # code omitted
        else:
            employee_input == "2"
            data = worksheet2.get_all_values()
            for row in data:
                print(row)
```

The expression `employee_input == 2` will evaluate to either True or False but then that result is not used. It also appears you are missing a `break` statement if you do not want to repeatedly repeat the loop when the user enters "2". So my best guess at what you meant was:

```py
def employee_action():
    """
    Asks the user what they wish to do now that they're logged in.
    """
    while True:
        employee_input = input(
            "What do you wish to do today?\n1 Get Personal Data \n2 Get Survey Responses\n")
        if employee_input == "1":
            data = worksheet.get_all_values()
            for row in data:
                print(row)
            input("Press enter to continue.")
            break
        elif employee_input == "2":
            data = worksheet2.get_all_values()
            for row in data:
                print(row)
            input("Press enter to continue.") # I am not sure if this is also missing
            break
```

If so, you can reduce some code redundancy with:

```py
def employee_action():
    """
    Asks the user what they wish to do now that they're logged in.
    """
    while True:
        employee_input = input(
            "What do you wish to do today?\n1 Get Personal Data \n2 Get Survey Responses\n")
        if employee_input == "1":
            data = worksheet.get_all_values()
        elif employee_input == "2":
            data = worksheet2.get_all_values()
        else:
            continue
        for row in data:
            print(row)
        input("Press enter to continue.")
```

Or even:

```py
def employee_action():
    """
    Asks the user what they wish to do now that they're logged in.
    """
    while employee_input := input(
        "What do you wish to do today?\n1 Get Personal Data \n2 Get Survey Responses\n"
    ) not in ("1", "2"):
        continue

    if employee_input == "1":
        data = worksheet.get_all_values()
    else:
        data = worksheet2.get_all_values()
    for row in data:
        print(row)
    input("Press enter to continue.")
```

But this alternate re-coding would require you to modify your choices in two places if you added a third possible choice: (1) In the `while` loop you would need to add the third choice in the list of acceptable choices and (2) You would need to modify your `if ... else ...` statements. Thus, I would prefer the first alternate.